# I need help updating this java code to work on eclipse

Tags: java, computer-science

I found a java code that encodes and decodes a string but it is written in a much older java, what implementation can I make to update it?
It's supposed to use Queue to us the key set and encode the message given by the user then decode it, all printed out.

```
import jss2.CircularArrayQueue;
public class Codes{
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Encode and decode a message using a key of values stored in
   //  a queue.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
      public static void main ( String[] args)
      {
      int[] key = {5, 12, -3, 8, -9, 4, 10};
      Integer keyValue;

      String encoded = "", decoded = "";

      String message = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA " +
                       "computers are lousy actors.";

      CircularArrayQueue<Integer> keyQueue1 = new CircularArrayQueue<Integer>();
      CircularArrayQueue<Integer> keyQueue2 = new CircularArrayQueue<Integer>();

      // load key queue
      for (int scan=0; scan < key.length; scan++)
      {
         keyQueue1.enqueue (new Integer(key[scan]));
         keyQueue2.enqueue (new Integer(key[scan]));
      }

      // encode message
      for (int scan=0; scan < message.length(); scan++)
      {
         keyValue = keyQueue1.dequeue();
         encoded += (char) ((int)message.charAt(scan) + keyValue.intValue());
         keyQueue1.enqueue (keyValue);
      }

      System.out.println ("\n\nEncoded Message:\n\n" + encoded + "\n");

      // decode message
      for (int scan=0; scan < encoded.length(); scan++)
      {
         keyValue = keyQueue2.dequeue();
         decoded += (char) ((int)encoded.charAt(scan) - keyValue.intValue());
         keyQueue2.enqueue (keyValue);
      }

      System.out.println ("Decoded Message:\n\n" + decoded+"\n\n");
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).

Answer (score 0):

You declared the Variable `keyValue` with `Integer` but you have to do it with `int`.